# How to make this query as Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to load the trace from physical table which is store table name and trace path.

I would like to make `NewTableName` and `Tracepath` as dynamic which will take from variables.

My Input :

```
select * into NewTableName 
FROM fn_trace_gettable('Tracepath\tracename.trc' ,DEFAULT)
```

Output: Required Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'NewTableName';
DECLARE @Tracepath NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Tracepath\tracename.trc';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'select * into ' +  @TableName + '
FROM fn_trace_gettable(''' + @Tracepath + ''' ,DEFAULT)';

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: I am receiving Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
The name 'select * into Test_Trace
FROM fn_trace_gettable('path,DEFAULT)' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @SNR Sorry, I've fixed it, use: `EXEC (@sql)`

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt response. it helped me lot.

Comment: @SNR Glad to have been of help. Can you accept the answer or you do not know how to do that?

Comment: I am not so good at dynamic SQL. Why  I could not able to see the query for print (@sql).

Comment: @SNR What do you mean? And please answer to my question: Can you accept the answer if it was helpful for you or you do not know how to do that?